# How to exclude a substring in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

There is a line of text:

```
Lorem ~Ipsum~ is simply ~dummy~ text ~of~ the printing...
```

To find all the words enclosed in ~~ I use

```
re.search(r'~([^~]*)~', text)
```

Let's say it became necessary to use `~~` instead of `~`
`([^\~]+)` indicates to exclude the `~` character from the text within those characters
How do I make a regular expression to exclude a string of characters instead of just one?

That is, `~~Lor~em~~` should return `Lor~em`

The symbol of the new string must not be excluded and the length of the found string cannot be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier instead of a negated character set.

```
re.search(r'~~(.*?)~~', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`re.DOTALL` makes `.` match newline characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot exclude the newline character

Comment: I said I updated the answer. `re.DOTALL` includes the newline.